# Contains Duplicate Solution With Recursion Error? LeetCode

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to implement a solution to the Contains Duplicate Leet Code Question with Recursion
But It return an error when duplicate values are at the end of the array. E.G returns false. However I can't see why it does this.

```
    public static bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums, int i = 0) {
        
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++) {

            Console.WriteLine("for loop j:" + j + "for i:" + i + " " + nums[j] + " == " + nums[i] );
            
            if (nums[j] == nums[i]) { return  true; }   
        }

        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("i++ = " + i);

        if (i < nums.Length) {
            ContainsDuplicate(nums, i); 
        }

        return false;
       
    }
```

TestCases

```
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(ContainsDuplicate(new int[] { 1, 1 }));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(ContainsDuplicate(new int[] { 1, 2 }));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(ContainsDuplicate(new int[] { 2, 14, 18, 22, 22 }));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine(ContainsDuplicate(new int[] { 2, 22, 22 }));
                    break;
```

Output >> True, False, False, False
Returning false on last two test cases though it should return true.
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c945S.png)

Comment: Is the requirement that you only need to check the last two elements of the collection to see if they're the same?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `return` keyword after the `if (i < nums.Length)`.

You had:

```
ContainsDuplicate(nums, i);
```

You needed:

```
return ContainsDuplicate(nums, i);
```

Here's the full code:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums, int i = 0)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("for loop j:" + j + "for i:" + i + " " + nums[j] + " == " + nums[i]);
        if (nums[j] == nums[i]) { return true; }
    }
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine("i++ = " + i);
    if (i < nums.Length)
    {
        return ContainsDuplicate(nums, i);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's an alternative to consider:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums, int i = 0)
{
    if (nums.Length - 1 <= i)
        return false;
        
    return
        nums[i] == nums[i + 1]
        || ContainsDuplicate(nums, i + 1);
}
```

Or even this:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums, int i = 0) =>
    nums.Length <= i + 1
    ? false
    : (nums[i] == nums[i + 1]) || ContainsDuplicate(nums, i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums, int i = 0) {

for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++) {
    Console.WriteLine("for loop j:" + j + " for i:" + i + " " + nums[j] + " == " + nums[i] );
    
    if (nums[j] == nums[i]) { return  true; }   
}

i++;
Console.WriteLine("i++ = " + i);

if (i < nums.Length) {
    if (ContainsDuplicate(nums, i)) {  // Check if the recursive call returns true
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

}